# How can I define the density of the random vector $(X, T(X))$, where $T$ is some deterministic function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Here, $X$ is a random variable on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P$). My questions are the following:

1. It seems that the random vector $(X, T(X))$ induces a valid probability measure (distribution) on $\mathbb{R}^2$ via $\mu(B) = P((X, T(X)) \in B)$. However, I believe that the support of this distribution is the set $ S := \{(x, t) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : t = T(x)\}$, which is a one-dimensional (sub-manifold?) of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is this correct?
2. The measure $\mu$ above is clearly not dominated by two-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Indeed, $\lambda(S) = 0$ but $\mu(S) = 1$. How can I then define a density for the distribution of this random vector? With respect to what measure $\nu$ can I define such a density? (Maybe Hausdorff measure?)
3. Suppose I wanted to define the conditional distribution of $X$ given $T(X)$. Would it make sense to define this as the ratio of two densities? Perhaps the density in (2) normalized by a marginal density?

Comment: I guess for second question, $\mathit{Leb}\otimes \nu_{\mathcal{T}}$ would work, where $\nu_{\mathcal{T}}$ is the counting measure on the set $\mathcal{T}\equiv\{t\in\mathbb{R}:t=T(x)\text{ for some }x\in \mathbb{R}\}$. Counting measure on an uncountable set is still well-defined.

Comment: @Q9y5 Wouldn't this be infinite?